# Java: opening and outputting a file when the user inputs the name

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I have a homework assignment where I need to output a text ASCII file based on what the user inputs. I am not using direct path because when I turn it in the professor needs to be able to test it, so I have the text files in the src folder so just the name of the file can be used. However when I try to test it I'm getting a file not found error. I know I'm typing the file names in correctly, but is there something I'm missing in my code that is causing this? I'm trying to test the program and make sure it does everything it's supposed to, but I'm kind of stuck because I can't get the file to output.. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TileMap

{

/*
    FUNCTION NAME: Main ;
    INPUT: none.
    OUTPUT: a message to the user of this program, all of the
    prompts and a final display according to user specifications.
    PRECONDITIONS:  None.
    POSTCONDITIONS: Variables and calls made according to users input
                    output set to start on a new line.
    CALLERS: None.
    CALLES: askPermission, getParameters(), getImage(), and doTileJob().

*/

// Start of Main Function

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int MAXSIDE = 100;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char [][] buffer = new char [MAXSIDE][MAXSIDE];
        String fileName = "";
        int tilesAcross = 0;
        int tilesDown = 0;
        int imageHeight = 0;
        int imageWidth = 0;
        char userInput = 0;

        System.out.println("Would you like to tile an image in a file?");

        TileMap.askPermission(userInput);
        TileMap.getParameters(fileName, tilesAcross, tilesDown);
        TileMap.getImage(buffer, fileName, imageHeight, imageWidth);
        TileMap.doTileJob(buffer, fileName, tilesDown, tilesAcross, imageHeight, imageWidth);

    }

/*
    FUNCTION NAME: askPermission ;
    INPUT: none.
    OUTPUT: a message to the user of this program.
    PRECONDITIONS:  output set to start on a new line.
    POSTCONDITIONS: variable response has user's answer stored in it.
    CALLERS: the main program
    CALLES: None.

*/

    static boolean askPermission(char response)
        {
            char y = 0;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("If yes, type a 'y', else type 'n':");
            response = scan.next().charAt(0);

            boolean yes = (response == y);

            if(yes = true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }


/*
   FUNCTION NAME getParameters ;
   INPUT: the file name, number of tiles across and down.
   OUTPUT: message "Getting Image".
   PRECONDITIONS: the variable response has 'y' in it.
   POSTCONDITIONS: variables set with the values entered by user.
   CALLERS: the main program
   CALLEES: none
*/

    static void getParameters(String fileName, int tilesDown, int tilesAcross)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name: ");
        fileName = scan.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of tiles across you want: ");
        tilesAcross = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of tiles down you want: ");
        tilesDown = scan.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Getting Image...");

    }

/*
    FUNCTION NAME: getImage ;
    INPUT:the file name and the height and width of the pattern to be made.
    OUTPUT: the message "Getting Image".
    PRECONDITIONS: array for image declared, the variables fileName, 
                   imageHeight and imageWidth set with proper values.  
    POSTCONDITIONS: the image is stored in the array.
    CALLERS: the main program
    CALLEES: none
*/
    static void getImage(char [][] buffer,
                String fileName, int imageHeight, int imageWidth)
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try
        {       
            Scanner fstream = new Scanner(file);

            imageHeight = fstream.nextInt();
            imageWidth = fstream.nextInt();
        }


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

/*
    FUNCTION NAME: doTileJob;
    INPUT:the buffer with the image and the height and width of the
          pattern to be made, and the user's input for tilesAcross, and tilesDown.
    OUTPUT: the patterns structured according to users input.
    PRECONDITIONS: All of the variables are set and pattern is stored in 'buffer'.
    POSTCONDITIONS: Output displayed according to users input.
    CALLERS: the main program
    CALLEES: none
*/
//  This function uses for loops to display the images. The inner most for loop prints one line of the picture.

    static void doTileJob (char [] [] buffer , String fileName, int tilesDown, int tilesAcross, int imageHeight, int imageWidth)
        {
            buffer = new char[tilesDown][tilesAcross];

            for(int i=0; i < imageHeight; i++)
            {
                for(int w = 0; w < imageWidth; w++)
                {
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    for(int t = 0; t < tilesAcross; t++)
                    {
                        for(int a = 0; a < tilesDown; a++)
                        {
                            System.out.println(fileName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }





    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put the file in your classpath. Then your java program will be able to load it.

Comment: In `getParameters`, when you say `fileName = scan.nextLine()` you only modify the local `fileName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `askPermission` is not used. The fields that you update in your methods are local and they are not passed back to your main.

If you want to access fields in your class, you need to create an instance of the class. After, you can access the fields directly. Something like the code below might better serve your purpose.

```
class TileMap    
{
    static final int MAXSIDE = 100;
    char [][] buffer = new char [MAXSIDE][MAXSIDE];
    String fileName = "";
    int tilesAcross = 0;
    int tilesDown = 0;
    int imageHeight = 0;
    int imageWidth = 0;
    char userInput = 0;

// Start of Main Function

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TileMap tileMap = new TileMap();
        tileMap.exec();
    }

    private void exec()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to tile an image in a file?");

        if (askPermission()) {
          getParameters();
          getImage();
          doTileJob();
        }
    }

    // code without the static ...
}
```